# No of sections with no of rows in Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

How can I manage different no of the rows in different no of sections ? no of rows & sections are not fixed depends on another table view  in other class.Suppose If xxx section Header then it contains 5 rows ,another section header contain 4 rows. section header is the account title in table view from other class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Really Simple , Use below tableView delegates-

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  // return your another table view's array count here, on which no of sections depends.
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // use like this
  int noOfRows = 0; 

  if(section == 0)
  {
     noOfRows = x;
  }
  else if(section ==1)
  {
     noOfRows = y;
  }
  .
  .
  .
  else
 {  
    noOfRows = z;
 }
 return noOfRows;
}
```

x, y, z are NSInteger here

Comment: hey i know that method yar..but i cant do it exactly i want

Comment: I Confused about what i have to check in condition?

Comment: yup..its help me:Naina.thnks again

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
     return 3; or [yourarray count] // 3 sections 0,1,2
}
```

For different numver of rows in diffrent sections

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the sections.
    if(  section == 0) // first section with 5 rows
        return [[yourarray objectAtIndex:section] count];

     if(  section == 1) // 2nd section with 4 rows
        return  [[yourarray objectAtIndex:section]  count];

     if(  section == 2) // 3rd section with 57rows
         return  [[yourarray objectAtIndex:section] count];



}
```

Comment: section is not fix its depends on fecth from other class so i cant check like this

Comment: sections are in fecth from different array and all the rows have also differnt array

Answer (score 1):

In table view delegate method; it has:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
     return data.count;
}
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return [data objectAtIndex:section].count;
}
```

You can set your sections number and rows number in those two methods.

Of course you have to also configure your data to two dimension array.

Comment: Jason:- i Have to check section also..because its not fix u R right but i have to do like If(section=="xxx") return data.count..if(section=="yy") return different array count..

Comment: @success the answer of Jason is the one that you needed, if you look at the tableView -numberOfRowsInSection (2nd set of code) it checks each of the record from the array based on the section index and returns the number of records

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 if(  section == 0)
    return [array count];

 if(  section == 1)
    return [array2 count];

 if(  section == 2)
     return [array3 count];
}
```

Comment: But here how to dynamically give the values here...e.g:- u have if(section == 0). i dont want to hard code the value of 0,1,2 here. I am not sure about the total no of sections. How can we do it we want to return the no of rows dynamically for different sections?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0){
        return 5;
    }
    if (section == 1){
        return 10;
    }
    //etc.
}
```